# ConcurrentModificationException while iterating through Arraylist (not removing)

Tags: java, android, exception, concurrency

I currently have a problem with iterating through an ArrayList. I've read several posts here, but nothing seem to have resolved my problem. Here is my code:

```
//restaurants contains a list of all restaurants and i want to filter them
List<Restaurant> newList = new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
List<Restaurant> allRestaurants = new ArrayList<Restaurant>(restaurants);
if (query != null && query.length() > 0 && !query.equals("*")) {
            synchronized (allRestaurants) {
                for (Iterator<Restaurant> it = allRestaurants.iterator(); it
                        .hasNext();) {
                    Restaurant restaurant = it.next();
                    if (restaurant.getCity().contains(query)) {
                        synchronized (newList) {
                            newList.add(restaurant);
                        }
                    } else {
                        newList = allRestaurants;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is code was modified by me with several ideas i've read here (synchronized, using iterator instead of for-each-loop). I even have synchronized the whole method and still get an exception.

The exception is happening in following line:

```
Restaurant restaurant = it.next();
```

which I don't understand. I am not manipulating the list in this line. Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: you probably do not want to have a nested synchronized block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else{
    newList = allRestaurants;
}
```

That is almost certainly your issue.

Assigning `newList` to `allRestaurants` then adding to `newList` is causing your comodification.

That is after `newList = allRestaurants` any add to `newList` will update the mod count in `allRestaurants` and thus your error.

Comment: you are right..i also found it there. it should belong to the outer if-case

Comment: `Set<String> keys = obj.keySet();
    for (String key : keys) {}` how to avoid exception from this?

Answer (score 0):

In the else branch

```
else {
   newList = allRestaurants;
}
```

You set `newList` to be `allRestaurants`. The next modification `newList.add(restaurant);` changes the allRestaurants-list.

The exception is thrown when `it.next()` is called, because then the iterator checks if its source was changed.

Answer (score 0):

The failure starts with:

```
newList = allRestaurants;
```

which points both references to the same list (i.e. the one you are iterating over).  You then  do the following:

```
newList.add(restaurant);
```

modifying the list.  From the javadoc of `ConcurrentModificationException`:

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the else clause.

```
         newList = allRestaurants;
```

That's why you get exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the ArrayList that is used for iteration inside a loop; that is what ConcurrentModificationException says (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) and `newList = allRestaurants;` plus `newList.add(restaurant);`does potentially change the list `allRestaurants`.

So what you could do is

1. create another list
2. put items to modify in that list
3. add/remove the new list (`addAll` or `removeAll`) to your old one *after* the loop

Check out http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html for more.